# Trying to replace all objects in parent context with the ones in its child: merge policies?

Tags: ios, core-data, concurrency, nsmanagedobject, nsmanagedobjectcontext

This is my scenario: I have a parent `NSManagedObjectContext` in the main queue, and a child `NSManagedObjectContext` in a private queue. I pass a set of managed objects in the parent context to its child. Then, the child context have the managed objects from its parent, and then it is inserted new managed objects. I make some processing in the private queue with all the managed objects in the child context, the ones that came from the parent and its own new ones, and at the end of the process, I need to tell the parent:

- Which of its managed objects need to be deleted
- Which of its managed objects need to be replaced with the new managed
  objects in the child
- Which of the managed objects in the child need to be inserted into
  the parent

In addition, the parent context owns another managed objects that are not passed to the child and I need to be kept after applying the changes from the child.

I'm not able to find examples of an scenario similar to mine, please I need help.

Thanks so much.